# Python PIL save image after rotating

Tags: python, image, save, rotation, python-imaging-library

I'm having problem saving an image after rotating it. I mean, when I call the function save after rotating the image, nothing happens. The old image stays the same, and the same problem occurs with my save as function. I guess the problem lies in my rotate function:

```
 def right90 (root, image, panel, filemenu):
        image = image.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (image.size[0], image.size[1], 0, 0))
        panel.configure(image = image1)
        panel.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel.image = image1
```

Below is the save function I use. It doesn't seem to have any problem I guess.

```
def save(image, filename):
    image.save(filename)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies. I really hope someone can help me find it. Thanks.

**Edited**

Below is the function where I declare the variables global. This is used for open an image file and use the file's info to assign value to the variables.

```
def display(root):
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All Files","*"),("All Picture Files","*bmp; *.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.tif; *.tiff")])

    global image
    global panel
    try:
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
        root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (image.size[0], image.size[1], 0, 0))
        panel.configure(image = image1)
        panel.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel.image = image1

    except NameError:        
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
        root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (image.size[0], image.size[1], 0, 0))
        panel= Label(root, image = image1)
        panel.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        panel.image = image1
```

And following is the code I wrote to call the rotate function. In case anyone needs it.

```
rotatemenu.choices.add_command(label="rotate right 90°", command = lambda:img.right90(root, image, panel, filemenu))
```

Comment: Could it be that `image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)` takes the `image` from the function call rather than the one described in the line just above it? Try changing its name?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you call `save`, you pass a variable that references the original image. Just guessing, because `right90` does not `return image`.

Comment: actually I'm not sure about your suggestion because my `image` is a global variable. Then when its value is changed (by being assigned to image.transpose) then its changed globally right?

Comment: If you want to modify a global variable inside a function, you must also declare it `global` inside that function. (But usually it is better to avoid such an approach altogether)

Comment: `image` is a global variable in the main method where I call the name of the function as a menu command, but it is used as a parameter in that command. And Python doesn't allow declaring a parameter a global variable. It sounds a little bit complicated I guess.

Comment: But it is true that when I assign the new value for the parameter, the value of the global variable doesn't change. I have no idea how to fix it though.

Comment: @pinkcupcake You need to rethink the structure of your application. A possible approach is to create a class: all those functions become methods of the class and global variables become instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Is is necessary to have both variable names, `image` and `image1`? I think that could be potentially a source of problems and I agree with @janne Karila, you are most likely not returning the changed image.

Can you do a `image.show()`/`image1.show()` inside your `right90` function and see what it shows?

Comment: when I click rotate (I use GUI here), the image is rotated but when I click save, nothing happens. And I use image1 so I can add it to the label (which requires a PhotoImage)

Comment: could you post the code that calls both functions? I'm not sure using global variables is that beneficial, so that's a bit of a concern re problems.

Comment: I added more details in my question. I'm really confused too, because I have some other functions used to change the RGB values of images, and I display the image the same way as I did for rotation, but the save function works fine, so I still believe that the problem lies in the rotate function.

Comment: @pinkcupcake Not quite sure what to suggest (not familiar with the GUI elements you are using) other than selectively commenting out parts, or substituting other functions inside `right90()` just for testing if the image changes and the changes stick. Finally, is the PIL `rotate()` function somehow limited for your needs?

Comment: the function works fine when I test it in a simple program and I think it's adequate for me. Thanks for discussing though!